# @font-face not working with www - firefox

Tags: html, css, font-face

In my site i am using specific font with this code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'monotype';
src: url('/static_frontend/monotype.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('/static_frontend/monotype.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('/static_frontend/monotype.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('/static_frontend/monotype.ttf')  format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
}
```

When I open the site with www. the font not loads in firefox. In every other browsers everything is fine. In firefox font works only without www.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem please write.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle with your code?

Comment: Your code contains no “www.”, yet the text describes “www.” as essential.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts). If that's not viable enough for you, I encountered a similar issue a while back. It happened because the fonts were on a separate domain or subdomain than the original files.

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason to be for this was because base URL was always set to without www. and the other style sheet was linked without www. as well, made path relative and it works just fine!